# With Css responsive media query, my child div is not accepting the margins that i am putting in.

Tags: html, css

I know this was a wrong and confusing title, but i am confused myself about this code. I am basically a UI designer who works closely with a very good developer, unfortunately due to some family problems my developer is not available for next week or so and i have a very urgent project to complete. I am a newbie to css so this code will be really messy, i really hope and pray that you guys can help me out.

So here is the problem, i am designing a responsive site, the desktop version is ready. In the version for the smaller resolutions i am facing the following problem. This section

```
<div class="promo_container">

<div class="promo one"><div class="content"><h3>Dashboard</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p></div>
</div>
<div class="promo two"><div class="content"><h3>Accounts</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p></div>
</div>
<div class="promo three"><div class="content"><h3>Forecast</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

With this css for the desktop version

```
.promo_container {
    max-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 75px;
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
}


.promo.one {
    background: url(../images/promo1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
    width: 326px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.promo.two { background: url(../images/promo2.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: left;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
    width: 326px;}

.promo.three { background: url(../images/promo3.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
float: left;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
    width: 326px;;
}

.promo_container .promo .content {
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

works fine but when i use this css for the tablet resolution

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 800px){

.promo_container {
    width: 100%;


    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
     overflow: auto;
}

.promo.one { background: url(../images/promo1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: none;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
    width:200px; 
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.promo.two { background: url(../images/promo2.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
clear: both;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
    width: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;}

.promo.three { background: url(../images/promo3.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
float: none;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
    width: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    }

.promo_container .promo .content {
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    line-height: 2em;
}
}
```

the result is that these promos all stack to the left of the screen While I want them to be at the center of the page.(I wish could attach the images but i don't have the privileges for that on stackoverflow yet.)

Now the second problem is that as you can see i have set the OVERFLOW to auto, the reason was that the these promos were coming over the content of the next div which is

```
<div class="testimonial">
<div class="testimonial-content"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.<br/><br/><b>-Lorem Consecteular</b></p></div>
</div>
```

With CSS

```
.testimonial {
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;


}
.testimonial .testimonial-content {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.testimonial-content p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

They don't have the same parent div and with the overflow set to auto the promos are coming with their own scroll bar so can you point out where i have made the mistake. As i said my friends i am a newbie, so maybe i have made a couple(or perhaps more :( ) blunders here but i will really appreciate if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to assume here about what you want the final solution to be, but I'll answer as best I can.

It sounds like you're learning some CSS for the first time, so I'll be quick with some pointers, but also get you an answer quickly, which is what it sounds like you're more interested in.

A couple things I've done in the code I'm sharing.

You can let the content dictate the height to allow your page to be truly flexible. If you have to put a height on your promos, that's ok, but the height of .promo_container can now be dictated by the height of your .promo elements.

You can declare common things on your .promo class, and then declare specific things on each .promo.one, .promo.two, .promo.three item.

When you enter your media query, you only have to *undo* or *override* properties that you've already stated. So, there's no need to list the exact same properties for .promo_container again. (For instance, margin-right: auto; and margin-left: auto;)

There's a lot to learn about how floats behave, and how the box-model responds to floats. If you are interested, read up on it here when you get some more time. http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

One of the main issues I see is that you didn't set float:none on each of your .promo items in the media query, so some of them are trying to float still. You are using a mixture of clear and float on the .promo items in the media query, but it's not getting the job done.

Lastly, depending on your needs, I would consider changing your media query to include max-width: 980px so that your .promos stack vertically as soon as the browser hits that width.

Anyway, this should get you started. Again, hard to tell what end result you are looking for, but hopefully you can work with and learn from this.

So, try this to begin...

**Some CSS To Try**

```
.promo_container {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 75px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.promo {
    float: left;
    width: 326px;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
}


.promo.one {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.promo.two { 
    background-position: 0px 3px;
}

.promo.three {
    background-position: 0px 3px;
}

.promo_container .promo .content {
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    line-height: 2em;
}

/* Media query for Promos */
@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 800px){

    .promo_container {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .promo {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}


/* Testimonies */
.testimonial {
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.testimonial .testimonial-content {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 30px;
}

.testimonial-content p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Best of luck.

Comment: jon, you sir are a life saver :) thanks a lot for taking time for this, it works perfectly except for the third promo, it was again struck to the left of the screen but i removed the inline-block and it is in the middle as well.  Just one more favor, by looking at my css skills (or rather the lack of it :) )can you please guide me to a good online course i can jump start with. Thanks a lot again, you are the man.

Comment: Doh! That inline-block property was not supposed to be in there. I must have copied and pasted it from what I was testing. Glad you were able to figure that out.

Comment: Regarding online courses, there are lots of great resources out there. A simple google search will get you more than you can handle. However, check out some articles on CSS by Smashing Magazine: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/tag/css/  Also check out Codeacademy. They have a course in web fundamentals: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web Finally, there are some fantastic courses at Treehouse. They aren't free, but I suggest you sign up for an account and start with this course: http://teamtreehouse.com/learning-adventures/become-a-web-designer  - Good luck Babur!